# pdf-tools auctex question with split buffers

Tags: auctex, pdf-tools

I run auctex with the latex source on the left half buffer and corresponding pdf on the right half (using C-x 3 to split the buffer). I then split the left half buffer into 2 so as two work on different parts of the latex source file. Similarly I split the right hand buffer into two so as to view the two corresponding pdf parts. **Is there some way of doing forward/reverse search between the top left latex source and top right pdf;  and a forward/reverse search between the bottom left latex source and bottom right pdf?** This would help a lot when working on a large latex document. Right now, the top left and bottom left latex source do forward/backward search  with the top right pdf; the bottom right pdf seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution at the bottom of this answer does not work anymore after https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/f646675cd1637948b2df2351a9666792ea8251ea

The extra argument `DEDICATE` of `window--display-buffer` has been removed by that commit.

Since `window--display-buffer` does consider `display-buffer-mark-dedicated` anyway maybe Emacs does like the OP wanted out-of-the-box.

Otherwise you can use the following modified code:

```el
(defun display-buffer-beside-selected (buffer alist)
  "Try displaying BUFFER in a window beside the selected window.
If there is a window below the selected one and that window
already displays BUFFER, use that window.
If that attempt fails and there is a non-dedicated window
beside the selected one, use that window.
The left or right hand side is chosen if ALIST contains
the cons (side . left) or (side . right), respectively."
  (let (window)
    (or (and (setq window (window-in-direction (cdr (assq 'side alist))))
         (eq buffer (window-buffer window))
         (window--display-buffer buffer window 'reuse alist))
    (and (setq window (window-in-direction (cdr (assq 'side alist))))
         (not (window-dedicated-p window))
         (window--display-buffer
          buffer window 'reuse alist)))))

(defun my-display-buffer-right (fun &rest args)
  "Use `display-buffer-in-side-window' as `display-buffer-overriding-action'.
Then run FUN with ARGS."
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-beside-selected (side . right))))
    (apply fun args)))

(defun my-display-buffer-left (fun &rest args)
  "Use `display-buffer-in-side-window' as `display-buffer-overriding-action'.
Then run FUN with ARGS."
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-beside-selected (side . left))))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view :around #'my-display-buffer-right)
(advice-add 'pdf-sync-backward-search-mouse :around #'my-display-buffer-left)
```

---

You can set the preferred window via the `ACTION` for `display-buffer`, which see. That also works for commands that use `display-buffer`.

From all the possibilities for setting the `ACTION` the variable `display-buffer-overriding-action` has the highest priority.

The following code shows how to define the action you want and how to set `display-buffer-overriding-action` for the commands you need.

```el
(defun display-buffer-beside-selected (buffer alist)
  "Try displaying BUFFER in a window beside the selected window.
If there is a window below the selected one and that window
already displays BUFFER, use that window.
If that attempt fails and there is a non-dedicated window
beside the selected one, use that window.
The left or right hand side is chosen if ALIST contains
the cons (side . left) or (side . right), respectively."
  (let (window)
    (or (and (setq window (window-in-direction (cdr (assq 'side alist))))
         (eq buffer (window-buffer window))
         (window--display-buffer buffer window 'reuse alist))
    (and (setq window (window-in-direction (cdr (assq 'side alist))))
         (not (window-dedicated-p window))
         (window--display-buffer
          buffer window 'reuse alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)))))

(defun my-display-buffer-right (fun &rest args)
  "Use `display-buffer-in-side-window' as `display-buffer-overriding-action'.
Then run FUN with ARGS."
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-beside-selected (side . right))))
    (apply fun args)))

(defun my-display-buffer-left (fun &rest args)
  "Use `display-buffer-in-side-window' as `display-buffer-overriding-action'.
Then run FUN with ARGS."
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action '(display-buffer-beside-selected (side . left))))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view :around #'my-display-buffer-right)
(advice-add 'pdf-sync-backward-search-mouse :around #'my-display-buffer-left)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That works perfectly! I have a related new question which I will post.